# Limited directory and subdirectory listing with links

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to list out directories and sub directories (one level deep) as part of my navigation but i can't figure out how to limit the depth of the search.

What i want to achieve:

```
|- <p>Directory</p>
||- <a>Sub Directory</a>
||- <a>Sub Directory</a>
|- <p>Directory</p>
||- <a>Sub Directory</a>
||- <a>Sub Directory</a>
```

Right now i'm using the code bellow to list a directory and link it but it does not include sub directories

```
$emailDirectory = "../";
$allPhpFiles = scandir($emailDirectory);
$phpfiles = array_diff($allPhpFiles, array('.', '..'));

<p>Other Emails</p>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile) 
            {
                echo '<li><a href="../'.$phpfile.'">'.$phpfile.'</a></li>';
            }?>
    </ul>
```

I also found on here someone talking about listing sub directories

```
function page_title($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$fp) 
        return null;

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
    if (!$res) 
        return null; 

    // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = trim($title);
    return $title;
}

<?php function listFolderFiles($dir){
$ffs = scandir($dir);
echo '<ol>';
foreach($ffs as $ff){
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
        echo '<li>'.$ff;
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('../../'); ?>
```

Which is great but they're not links and it goes into the sub directories and lists the items in them but as i said before i'd like it to cut off at the sub directories and not go any deeper.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter with depth

```
<?php 
    function listFolderFiles($dir, $deep = 0, $depth_limit = 1){
    if($deep > $depth_limit ) return;
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff, ++$deep);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    }

    listFolderFiles('../../'); 
?>
```